# Can i set up record types and arrays of record types PHP?

Tags: php

In pascal and delphi I am able to set up a custom type such as

```
myrecord = type
name : string;
number: integer;
end;
```

The advantage of this I can then do an array of that type so I can run code like records[i].name = ... ECT. Can I do this in PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot create custom type, but you can use [objects](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php) to hold information about your records. You can push objects into array afterwards and do exactly what you described.

```
class MyRecord {
    public $name;
    public $number;
}

$record1 = new MyRecord();
$record1->name = "foo";
...

$records = array($record1, ...);

foreach ($records as $record) {
    echo $record->name;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

PHP is loosely typed, so you don't have to declare all the properties of a class. Instead, you can do:

```
$obj = new stdClass();
$obj->name = "Derrik";
echo $obj->name;
```

StdClass is the name of the default class.

Answer (score 1):

No. PHP is a language with dynamic typization, so you cannot do it.